# Java Validate Field Conditional On Class Level

Tags: java, validation

Say I have the following Pojos and constraints.

```java
public class Pojo1 {
    @NotNull
    private String field1;
    @NotNull
    private String field2; // <--- I only want this NotNull in Pojo3.java but not in Pojo2.java
}

public class Pojo2 {
    @Valid
    private Pojo1 pojo1;
}

public class Pojo3 {
    @Valid
    private Pojo1 pojo1;
    @Valid
    private Pojo2 pojo2;
}
```

I want Pojo1.field2 to be validated ONLY under Pojo3 but not Pojo2. In other words, the following JSON should pass validation

```json
{
   "pojo1": {
      "field1": "something",
      "field2": "something"
   },
   "pojo2": {
      "pojo1": {
         "field1": "something"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you trigger validation?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko validation is processed by objects from `javax.validation` package and is triggered automatically for input objects annotated with `@Valid` by your mvc environment (for example Spring `RestController` handles it). You can also trigger it manually using `javax.validation.Validator`. Excellent intro here: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation).

Comment: @SebastianM yes, I'm aware of that. But there is another way to manually trigger validation with `javax.validation.Validator.validate(T object, Class... groups);` method. That's why I'm asking about the way of triggering

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I'm using Spring to handle validation. But I can use manual validation if needed. I've looked into group validation but I don't think it will solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing Pojo1.field2 validation with custom validation on Pojo3 for example like this:

```
public class Pojo1 {

    @NotNull
    private String field1;

    // @NotNull // don't validate it generally
    private String field2;
}
public class Pojo2 {
    @Valid
    private Pojo1 pojo1;
}

public class Pojo3 {

    @Valid
    private Pojo1 pojo1;

    @Valid
    private Pojo2 pojo2;

    @javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue
    public boolean isPojo1Valid() {
        return pojo1 == null || pojo1.getField2() != null;
    }
}
```